# $q.all() - responses returned not in sequence

Tags: angularjs, promise, es6-promise, angular-promise

I have an array of promises in the following order:

```
promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise 4, promise5];
```

**Each promise is a http call..**

I tried to retrieve the responses by so:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function f(responses) { 
    console.log(responses);
});
```

And would expected the responses returned to be in the following order:

`response1, response2, response3, response4, response5`

But sometimes the order of the responses returned are random as such:

`response1, response2, response4, response5, response3`

Does $q.all() method not maintain the order of responses returned?

Are there other methods that maintain the order of responses returned if $q.all() doesn’t? Would prefer not to use chain promising as my promises can be a long list..

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, $q.all() **does not** maintain the order of responses returned. It just triggers a rejection if one or more of the provided promises is rejected, or triggers a resolution if/when all of the provided promises are resolved.

There are no other methods in that API for maintaining the order of responses in a list of promises.

A generalized implementation of promise chaining is possible, but very convoluted.